# How to parse S-expression in Erlang?

Tags: parsing, erlang, robocup

I am implementing client agent for **Robocup Soccer simulator** in **Erlang**. Simulator sends sensory information to client in form of **S-expressions**. Like this

```
(see 15 ((f c) 2 0 0 0) ((f r t) 64.1 -32) ((f r b) 64.1 32) ((f g r b) 55.1 7) 
 ((g r) 54.6 0) ((b) 2 0 -0 0) ((l r) 54.6 90)) 
(see 16 ((f r t) 72.2 -44) ((f r b) 54.1 20) ((f g r b) 52.5 -10) ((g r) 54.1 -17)
 ((l r) 51.4 -89))
```

Simulator sends such type of sensor informatio in each cycle(100-200 msec). 
The main format of the information is:

```
(see Time ObjInfo ObjInfo . . . )
```

The ObjInfos are of the format below:

> (ObjName Distance Direction
>   [DistChange DirChange [BodyFac- ingDir
>   HeadFacingDir]])

where the objects are like:
(b) Ball, (g r) Right goal, (f ...) represents various flags.

What I want is to **parse** this information and **store/update in some database(record)** to use for analysis.
The main difficulty I am facing is to Parse this information.
Please **suggest me some way of doing this**? (does Erlang contain any library for such work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yecc and Leex are your friends: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/parsetools/index.html

Leex is a lexical analyzer generator for Erlang which will tokenize your data. Yecc is LALR-1 parser generator that can parse your tokens into meaningful structures.

There's a good blog post by Relops, [Leex And Yecc](http://relops.com/blog/2014/01/13/leex_and_yecc/), detailing some of the basics.

Answer (score 2):

If you load [LFE (Lisp Flavoured Erlang)](https://github.com/rvirding/lfe) it contains a lisp scanner and parser. The modules you need are `lfe_scan`, `lfe_parse` and `lfe_io` which wraps the other two. The scanner is written using `leex` (source is `lfe_scan.xrl`) while the parser is hand written as there are some features of how `yecc` works which didn't quite fit.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be to just write a small LISP reader.

The quick and (very) dirty way (for initial testing ONLY): Substitute whitespace with a comma, "(" with "{" and ")" with "}". Then you have an erlang literal.

Have a look at `erl_scan` and `erl_parse`.